# Printing the elements two linked list behaving weird

Tags: c++, pointers

I wrote a linked list with following code.  The first print is working,  but second print is not.

```
int main() {
    Node *A, *B;


    B = InsertTail(B, 2);
    B = InsertTail(B, 3);
    B = InsertTail(B, 8);
    B = InsertTail(B, 10);

    Print(B);

    A = InsertTail(A, 1);
    A = InsertTail(A, 5);
    A = InsertTail(A, 10);
    A = InsertTail(A, 12);
    A = InsertTail(A, 16);

    Print(A);

    return 0;
}
```

Function `InsertTail` inserts data in second argument to the end of the list and returns the `head` of the list. And `Print` function prints the list if all elements.

Print function is implemented as

```
void Print(Node *head)
{
    Node *current = head;
    if(head == NULL){ return; }
    while(current != NULL){
        cout << current->data << endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

And, `InsertTail is implemented as`

```
Node* InsertTail(Node *head,int data)
{
    Node *current = new Node, *temp = head;
    current->data = data;
    current->next = NULL;

    if(temp==NULL){return current;}
    else{
        while(temp->next != NULL){ temp=temp->next;}
        temp->next = current;
    }
    return head;
}
```

I tried to debug it, the first value of `A` is fine but on second value, there is `data = 1836017711`. Here is a screenshot.
[image]

Comment: You're calling `InsertTail` with an unitialized pointer?

Comment: @imreal what happened after I did it? Also thanks, I fixed it :)

Comment: You have no guarantee that in your first insert `head` will be `NULL`, try `Node *A = nullptr, *B = nullptr;`

Comment: 90% of the time, your compiler should issue a warning about this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not seem to initialize neither `A` neither `B` before the calls. Judging by your `Print` function, I suppose that `A` and `B` should be initialized with `NULL`:

```
Node *A=NULL, *B=NULL;
```

Without initialization, I guess this is undefined behavior, anything can happen. In simplest case, `A` and `B` just happen to point to a random place in memory with random contents (and you are very lucky to have even `B` work).

P.S. Why do you insert at tail, but keep a pointer to head only? I suggest you keep a pointer to tail too so that you do not go along all list each time.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize your lists with NULL, while you are initializing them with garbage:

```
Node *A, *B;
```

It should be

```
Node *A=NULL, *B=NULL;
```